# Adjusting Duration of scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, animation, duration, smooth-scrolling

I'm using JS to smooth scroll using anchor tags and IDs, and I'd like to adjust the duration of the smooth scroll animation.

Here's my code:

```js
    let anchorlinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]')
 
    for (let item of anchorlinks) {
        item.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
            let hashval = item.getAttribute('href')
            let target = document.querySelector(hashval)
            target.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth',
                block: 'start',
                duration: 200
            })
            history.pushState(null, null, hashval)
            e.preventDefault()
        })
    }
```

However, it still uses the default duration. I can't figure out any way to adjust the duration fo the animation.

Thanks!